# call bash function with bsub lsf within bash script

Tags: bash, lsf

I have a bash function i would like to bsub.  It is recursively called when i try to source the script, but if i don't source the script it doesn't seem to recognize my function.  How do I correctly call besub on a function within the same script file?

my_script(should print "12345"):

```
#! /bin/sh
function myFunct {
echo $1
}

bsub -q myQueue "source ./my_script; myFunct 12345"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a.bash` may look like this

```
#! /bin/bash

export input=$1
function myFunct {
echo "$input"
}

# This is if you want to call bsub outside the bash
#  Use bsub -q Queue `./a.bash 12345`

myFunct "$input"  


# Put bsub inside and call the script
# ./a.bash 12345

bsub -q myQueue `myFunct "$input"`
```

Comment: thx.  how would it look if i wanted to call bsub within a.bash? i want to do this because i have a forloop in my actual code.

Comment: Instead of `myFunct "$input"` you can write `bsub -q Queue \`myFunct "$input"\``.  Then execute as `./a.bash 12345`

Comment: ..thx again..but it doesn't seem to be able to find myFunct.  i tested it by replacing echo "$input" with 'mkdir myDir' and nothing gets created. any ideas?

Comment: Notice `$input` is the argument you have to provide to the script. Also check the permission of your script. Paste the error it shows when you execute the script.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35812/discussion-between-prostock-and-iamauser)

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten it to work with

```
bsub [...] bash -rcfile my_script.sh -i -c "myFunct 12345"
```